# UINavigationBar horizontal position

Tags: ios, iphone

Can I change horizontal position of UINavigationBar's title?

Like this image (MY ACCOUNT is the UINavigationBar title)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your own `UILabel`, assign it to your view controller's `navigationItem`'s `titleView`. You can left align the text in the label.

Comment: The back button itself reserves space, so while this will shift the text left, it will not get very close to the left edge even if there is no back button text. So far the work around I've found is making a custom UIView with a UILabel added to it that has a negative X transform on it, and setting that custom view to the NavigationItem.TitleView.. hoping to find something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Change the position of the navigationbar title will be difficult.

In my experience, I could use either one of below two ways;

1. Set left button.
   When you set title and image both to UIButton, it will be exactly same look as like as you want.
   And set that button to the left button of navigationItem.
2. You can create new view which contains UILabel which have that position and set that view to navigationItem's titleView